# numpy genfromtxt date conversion error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am loading a file using `numpy.genfromtxt` and some of the fields are in a date format, however, when I setup a converter to process these items I get an error that I am not sure how to address (see below):

```
strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
```

At this point, my objective is to find a simple way to load files (using genfromtxt) and convert selected columns from date format to an integer (epoch, for example) -- however, I am looking for any approach that will work (not necessarily the one I have illustrated).

Any help is appreciated.

(details below)

- Running in virtualenv
- Using MacOS
- Using Python v3.5

The file (abbreviated) is a simple CSV format:

```
SomeField,SomeDate
1,2013-08-16
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def main():
    pathRaw = 'data/homesite-quote-conversion/temp.csv'
    str2epoch = lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    converters = {1:str2epoch}
    dataset = np.genfromtxt(open(pathRaw,'rb'), converters=converters, dtype=None, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
  main()
File "test.py", line 8, in main
  dataset = np.genfromtxt(open(pathRaw,'rb'), converters=converters, dtype=None, delimiter=',', skip_header=1)
File "{user-directory}/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1731, in genfromtxt
  converter.iterupgrade(current_column)
File "{user-directory}/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/_iotools.py", line 766, in iterupgrade
_ strict_call(_m)
File "/{user-directory}/.virtualenvs/demo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/_iotools.py", line 688, in _strict_call
  new_value = self.func(value)
File "test.py", line 6, in <lambda>
  str2epoch = lambda x: time.mktime(time.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 494, in _strptime_time
  tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 306, in _strptime
  raise TypeError(msg.format(index, type(arg)))
TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that `time.strptime` expects the first argument to be a [`str`, not `bytes`](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3):

```
>>> x = b'2013-08-16'    # x is bytes
>>> import time
>>> time.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'bytes'>
>>> time.strptime(x.decode('ascii'), '%Y-%m-%d')   # x.decode('ascii') is a str
time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=228, tm_isdst=-1)
```

So you can avoid the error by using

```
def str2epoch(x):
    return time.mktime(time.strptime(x.decode('ascii'), '%Y-%m-%d'))
```